# R: Cast data back to original form

Tags: r, melt

I am trying to figure out how to create columns from a series of rowvalues for a variable. Here is a toy representation, I have a set `melted`:

```
          name variable value
        1  Dog       id     1
        2  Cat       id     2
        3 Fish       id     3
        4  Dog   number    23
        5  Cat   number    14
        6 Fish   number    27
```

Which I would like to look like this:

```
         ID Name Number
       1  1  Dog     23
       2  2  Cat     14
       3  3 Fish     27
```

What is the appropriate `cast` command to do so?

Comment: `dcast(melted, name ~ variable)`? Are you using "reshape" or "reshape2"? (Not that the result should matter in this case...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic syntax would look something like this:

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(melted, name ~ variable)
  name id number
1  Cat  2     14
2  Dog  1     23
3 Fish  3     27
```

Specify the dataset, then the IDs on the LHS of the fomula, then the new columns on the RHS. You're not doing any aggregation. Also, you don't *need* to specify the "value" column, though it is probably good practice to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

 melted %>% 
 spread(variable,value) %>% 
 arrange(id)
 #   name id number
 #1  Dog  1     23
 #2  Cat  2     14
 #3 Fish  3     27
```